yfinance error when combined with different function
I have been trying to debug this discord bot that i coded for almost a week now and cant seem to figure out why yfinance isnt fetching any pre-market data, even though it fetches pre-market data with other bots that I have worked on. I have pasted the code below any help would be greatly appreciated.
import discord
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
from discord.ext import tasks
from discord import Embed
import pytz
import asyncio

# Initialize the Discord client
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

# Track entry alerts and their times
entry_alerts = {}
trade_stats = {
    "total_trades": 0,
    "closed_trades": 0,
    "total_profit": 0.0,
    "win_trades": 0
}

# List of stocks to monitor
STOCKS = ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'META', 'NVDA', 'CVNA', 'SPY', 'QQQ']
CHANNEL_NAME = 'channel_name'  # Replace with channel name

# Define Inputs
StartTime = time(4, 0)  # Start time for the anchored regression
endtime = time(9, 29)  # End time for the anchored regression
Channel_1_Width = 0.70

# Timezone setup for EST
eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')

def get_pre_market_data(ticker):
    end_time = datetime.now(eastern).replace(hour=9, minute=30, second=0, microsecond=0)
    start_time = end_time - timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)  # 4:00 AM EST to 9:30 AM EST
    
    try:
        data = yf.download(ticker, start=start_time.date(), end=end_time.date(), interval='2m', prepost=True)
        
        if data.empty:
            print(f"No data found for {ticker}. It may be delisted or no pre-market data is available.")
            return pd.DataFrame()  # Return an empty DataFrame
        
        # Ensure the index is a DatetimeIndex
        if not isinstance(data.index, pd.DatetimeIndex):
            data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
        
        return data.between_time('04:00', '09:29')
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching data for {ticker}: {e}")
        return pd.DataFrame()  # Return an empty DataFrame on error

def calculate_LRC(df):
    df['time'] = df.index.time

    df['sec1'] = df.index.map(lambda x: (x - datetime.combine(x.date(), StartTime)).total_seconds())
    df['isTime1'] = ((df['sec1'] >= 0) & (df['sec1'].shift(1) < 0)) | ((df['sec1'] < df['sec1'].shift(1)) & (df['sec1'] >= 0))

    df['x'] = np.arange(len(df))
    df['nan'] = np.nan
    df['xx'] = np.where(df['isTime1'], df['x'], np.nan)
    df['xx'].ffill(inplace=True)
    df['firstBar'] = np.where(df['isTime1'], df['x'] + 1, np.nan)
    df['firstBar'].ffill(inplace=True)

    df['cond_y'] = np.where(df['time'] <= endtime, df['x'], np.nan)
    df['cond_y_max'] = df['cond_y'].max()

    df['y'] = np.where(df.index == 0, df['nan'], 
                       np.where((df['x'] >= df['firstBar']) & (df['x'] <= df['cond_y_max']), df['close'], df['nan']))
    df['y'].ffill(inplace=True)

    df['S_y'] = np.where(df['x'] == df['firstBar'], df['y'], 
                         np.where(df['x'] > df['firstBar'], df['S_y'].shift(1) + df['y'], df['nan']))
    df['S_y'].ffill(inplace=True)

    df['S_x'] = np.where(df['x'] == df['firstBar'], 1, 
                         np.where(df['x'] > df['firstBar'], df['S_x'].shift(1) + 1, df['nan']))
    df['S_x'].ffill(inplace=True)

    x0_ = df['xx'].max() - df['firstBar'].iloc[0]
    x1 = df.loc[df['y'].notna(), 'x'].iloc[-1]
    x0 = df.loc[df['x'] == x1 - x0_, 'x'].iloc[0]

    df['x_'] = np.where(df['x'] >= x1 - x0_, df['x'] - x0, np.nan)
    df['x_'].ffill(inplace=True)

    def E(y, n):
        return pd.Series([y[i:i+n].sum() for i in range(len(y) - n + 1)])

    df['Ex'] = E(df['x_'], x0_)
    df['Ey'] = E(df['y'], x0_)
    df['Exy'] = E(df['x_'] * df['y'], x0_)
    df['Exsq'] = E(df['x_'] ** 2, x0_)

    b = (x0_ * df['Exy'] - df['Ex'] * df['Ey']) / (x0_ * df['Exsq'] - df['Ex'] ** 2)
    a = (df['Ey'].iloc[-1] - b.iloc[-1] * df['Ex'].iloc[-1]) / x0_

    df['LR'] = a + b * df['x_']

    r = df['high'].rolling(2).max() - df['low'].rolling(2).min()
    Er = E(r, x0_) / x0_

    mean = df['S_y'] / df['S_x']
    df['SD'] = np.sqrt((1 / df['S_x']) * E((df['y'] - mean) ** 2, df['S_x']))

    df['LRL'] = np.where(df['x'] <= df['cond_y_max'], df['LR'], df['nan'])

    df['upper1'] = df['LRL'] + df['SD'].max() * Channel_1_Width
    df['lower1'] = df['LRL'] - df['SD'].max() * Channel_1_Width

    return df[['LRL', 'upper1', 'lower1']]

# Function to calculate 5 EMA on 5-minute time frame
def calculate_5_ema(data):
    data_5min = data.resample('5min').agg({'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last', 'Volume': 'sum'})
    data_5min['5EMA'] = data_5min['Close'].ewm(span=5, adjust=False).mean()
    return data_5min

async def get_stock_data(symbol):
    data = get_pre_market_data(symbol)
    
    if data.empty:
        return None, None  # Skip processing if no data is returned
    
    lrc_data = calculate_LRC(data)
    data_5min = calculate_5_ema(data)
    return lrc_data, data_5min

async def monitor_and_alert():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), name=CHANNEL_NAME)

    if channel is None:
        print("Channel not found. Please check the channel name.")
        return

    while True:
        current_time = datetime.now(eastern).time()
        market_open = time(9, 30)
        market_close = time(16, 0)

        if market_open <= current_time <= market_close:
            tasks = [get_stock_data(symbol) for symbol in STOCKS]
            results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

            for i, (lrc_data, data_5min) in enumerate(results):
                if lrc_data is None or data_5min is None:
                    print(f"Skipping {STOCKS[i]} due to lack of data.")
                    continue

                last_price = lrc_data['LRL'].iloc[-1]
                upper1 = lrc_data['upper1'].iloc[-1]
                lower1 = lrc_data['lower1'].iloc[-1]
                current_time = lrc_data.index[-1]

                last_ema = data_5min['5EMA'].iloc[-1]

                if last_price > upper1 and symbol not in entry_alerts:
                    contracts = await get_option_contracts(symbol, last_price, contract_type='call')
                    if contracts:
                        await send_alert(
                            channel, "ENTRY Long/Calls", discord.Color.green(),
                            f"{symbol} broke the upper channel at ${last_price:.2f}.\n"
                            f"Suggested Contracts:\n"
                            f"1. {symbol} {contracts[0]['strike']} CALL (Exp: {contracts[0]['expiry']}) - Price: ${contracts[0]['price']:.2f}\n"
                            f"2. {symbol} {contracts[1]['strike']} CALL (Exp: {contracts[1]['expiry']}) - Price: ${contracts[1]['price']:.2f}",
                            contracts[0]['price']
                        )
                        entry_alerts[symbol] = {
                            'type': 'long', 'time': current_time, 'price': last_price, 'contract': contracts[0], 'alerted_exit': False
                        }
                        trade_stats["total_trades"] += 1
                
                elif last_price < lower1 and symbol not in entry_alerts:
                    contracts = await get_option_contracts(symbol, last_price, contract_type='put')
                    if contracts:
                        await send_alert(
                            channel, "ENTRY Short/Puts", discord.Color.red(),
                            f"{symbol} broke the lower channel at ${last_price:.2f}.\n"
                            f"Suggested Contracts:\n"
                            f"1. {symbol} {contracts[0]['strike']} PUT (Exp: {contracts[0]['expiry']}) - Price: ${contracts[0]['price']:.2f}\n"
                            f"2. {symbol} {contracts[1]['strike']} PUT (Exp: {contracts[1]['expiry']}) - Price: ${contracts[1]['price']:.2f}",
                            contracts[0]['price']
                        )
                        entry_alerts[symbol] = {
                            'type': 'short', 'time': current_time, 'price': last_price, 'contract': contracts[0], 'alerted_exit': False
                        }
                        trade_stats["total_trades"] += 1
                
                if symbol in entry_alerts:
                    entry = entry_alerts[symbol]
                    time_diff = (current_time - entry['time']).total_seconds() / 60

                    if entry['type'] == 'long':
                        if time_diff <= 2.5 and last_price < upper1 and not entry['alerted_exit']:
                            await send_alert(channel, "EXIT False Breakout", discord.Color.orange(), f"{symbol} closed below the upper channel at ${last_price:.2f}.")
                            entry_alerts[symbol]['alerted_exit'] = True
                        elif time_diff >= 7.5 and last_price < upper1 and not entry['alerted_exit']:
                            await send_alert(channel, "EXIT Stopped Out", discord.Color.red(), f"{symbol} closed below the upper channel at ${last_price:.2f} after {time_diff:.1f} minutes.")
                            await track_trade_stats(channel, symbol, entry, last_price)
                            entry_alerts[symbol]['alerted_exit'] = True
                        elif last_price < last_ema and not entry['alerted_exit']:
                            await send_alert(channel, "EXIT Profit", discord.Color.blue(), f"{symbol} closed below the 5 EMA at ${last_price:.2f}.")
                            await track_trade_stats(channel, symbol, entry, last_price)
                            entry_alerts[symbol]['alerted_exit'] = True

                    elif entry['type'] == 'short':
                        if time_diff <= 2.5 and last_price > lower1 and not entry['alerted_exit']:
                            await send_alert(channel, "EXIT False Breakout", discord.Color.orange(), f"{symbol} closed above the lower channel at ${last_price:.2f}.")
                            entry_alerts[symbol]['alerted_exit'] = True
                        elif time_diff >= 7.5 and last_price > lower1 and not entry['alerted_exit']:
                            await send_alert(channel, "EXIT Stopped Out", discord.Color.red(), f"{symbol} closed above the lower channel at ${last_price:.2f} after {time_diff:.1f} minutes.")
                            await track_trade_stats(channel, symbol, entry, last_price)
                            entry_alerts[symbol]['alerted_exit'] = True
                        elif last_price > last_ema and not entry['alerted_exit']:
                            await send_alert(channel, "EXIT Profit", discord.Color.blue(), f"{symbol} closed above the 5 EMA at ${last_price:.2f}.")
                            await track_trade_stats(channel, symbol, entry, last_price)
                            entry_alerts[symbol]['alerted_exit'] = True

        else:
            print("Market is closed. Waiting for market to open...")
            await asyncio.sleep(300)

        await asyncio.sleep(60)

async def track_trade_stats(channel, symbol, entry, last_price):
    contract_price = entry['contract']['price']
    exit_price = last_price
    profit = exit_price - contract_price

    trade_stats["total_profit"] += profit
    trade_stats["closed_trades"] += 1
    if profit > 0:
        trade_stats["win_trades"] += 1

    await send_alert(
        channel, "EXIT", discord.Color.blue(),
        f"{symbol} exited the position at ${last_price:.2f}. Contract: {symbol} {entry['contract']['strike']} {entry['contract']['contract_type']} (Exp: {entry['contract']['expiry']}). "
        f"Entry Price: ${entry['contract']['price']} -> Exit Price: ${exit_price}. Profit: ${profit:.2f}"
    )

@tasks.loop(time=pd.to_datetime("09:00:00").time())
async def scheduled_reset_and_recalculate():
    await daily_reset_and_recalculate()

async def daily_reset_and_recalculate():
    stock_symbols = ["AAPL", "TSLA", "META", "NVDA", "CVNA"]

    for symbol in stock_symbols:
        await get_stock_data(symbol)

async def send_alert(channel, title, color, description):
    embed = Embed(title=title, description=description, color=color)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}')
    scheduled_reset_and_recalculate.start()
    await monitor_and_alert()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower() == "!bot stats":
        stats = (f"**Bot Stats:**\n"
                 f"Total Trades: {trade_stats['total_trades']}\n"
                 f"Closed Trades: {trade_stats['closed_trades']}\n"
                 f"Total Profit: ${trade_stats['total_profit']:.2f}\n"
                 f"Winning Trades: {trade_stats['win_trades']}\n"
                 f"Win Rate: {trade_stats['win_trades'] / trade_stats['closed_trades'] * 100 if trade_stats['closed_trades'] > 0 else 0:.2f}%")
        await send_alert(message.channel, "Bot Stats", discord.Color.blue(), stats)

client.run('token')

I have been receiving this error in the console
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed

1 Failed download:
['AAPL']: YFPricesMissingError('$%ticker%: possibly delisted; No price data found  (2m 2024-08-13 -> 2024-08-13)')
No data found for AAPL. It may be delisted or no pre-market data is available.
$TSLA: possibly delisted; No price data found  (2m 2024-08-13 -> 2024-08-13)
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed

1 Failed download:
['TSLA']: YFPricesMissingError('$%ticker%: possibly delisted; No price data found  (2m 2024-08-13 -> 2024-08-13)')
No data found for TSLA. It may be delisted or no pre-market data is available.
$META: possibly delisted; No price data found  (2m 2024-08-13 -> 2024-08-13)
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed

1 Failed download:
['META']: YFPricesMissingError('$%ticker%: possibly delisted; No price data found  (2m 2024-08-13 -> 2024-08-13)')
No data found for META. It may be delisted or no pre-market data is available.
$NVDA: possibly delisted; No price data found  (2m 2024-08-13 -> 2024-08-13)
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed

1 Failed download:
['NVDA']: YFPricesMissingError('$%ticker%: possibly delisted; No price data found  (2m 2024-08-13 -> 2024-08-13)')
No data found for NVDA. It may be delisted or no pre-market data is available.
$CVNA: possibly delisted; No price data found  (2m 2024-08-13 -> 2024-08-13)
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed

1 Failed download:
['CVNA']: YFPricesMissingError('$%ticker%: possibly delisted; No price data found  (2m 2024-08-13 -> 2024-08-13)')
No data found for CVNA. It may be delisted or no pre-market data is available.
Skipping AAPL due to lack of data.
Skipping TSLA due to lack of data.
Skipping META due to lack of data.
Skipping NVDA due to lack of data.
Skipping CVNA due to lack of data.

I have tried recoding the pre_market data function of the code, as well as recoding the LRC calculation since the two parts go hand in hand. One thing i have tried is changing the code to regular market hours 9:30-4:00 and the bot seems to work. but my strategy requires the LRC to be anchored at 4:00am to 9:29am. So using the LRC anchored during regular market hours is useless.

that's a lot of code you expect folks to go through, suggest you  post a minimal functional example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). does the yfinance code work as a standalone ?

If you want only 4-5 hours of data remove call to the .date() method when calling yf.download. This also will fix your problem.

def get_pre_market_data(ticker):
    end_time = datetime.now(tz=eastern).replace(hour=9, minute=30, second=0, microsecond=0) 
    start_time = end_time - timedelta(hours=4, minutes=30)  # 4:00 AM EST to 9:30 AM EST
    
    try:
        data = yf.download(ticker, 
                           start=start_time, 
                           end=end_time, 
                           interval='2m', 
                           prepost=True)
    ...


if doing multiple instruments, take a look at https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/wiki/Tickers function
